# Why does my website show two headers on a smartphone?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

For some reason my website shows two headers (the Desktop Header + the Mobile Header) when I open it on my smartphone. Can you imagine what the cause for that is?

https://www.globalmarshallplan.org/

Comment: please add an [mcve]

Comment: Without a minimal code, we can't help you. If you're using bootstrap, you can add the class `.d-sm-none` to desktop header

Answer (score 1):

Because in small screen resolution appears additional block for header, but existing block (for desktop) don't hide.

Comment: @dharmang, Thanks for corrections. My English is poor

Answer (score 0):

(x-hide-xs x-hide-sm x-hide-md)  add these classes to the desktop version

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I am a newbie so what I did was just adding your suggested lines to the CSS which didn't work out. What exactly do I need to do if I want the desktop version header to hide?

Comment: This is working for me, you need to add those classes in the html file

Comment: <div class="e3947-7 x-bar x-bar-top x-bar-h x-bar-relative x-bar-outer-spacers x-**hide-xs x-hide-sm x-hide-md**" ......   like this

Comment: The problem here is simple you have not used any rules or specified any rules class for hiding desktop version header in mobiles.

Comment: Maybe I need to specify - I'm using wordpress.

Comment: Inside header.php you can find the codes